# How can I search in a list in a pandas column?

Tags: python, pandas, list

I've been given a set of poorly formatted data to clean up, there are several columns of data which contain multiple pieces of information which need to be split into multiple columns each.
One example is a column called DaysOfWeek which contains the days that a person can work, plus a free text field. I want to create 8 columns, 1 for each day of the week, and one for anything that isn't a day of the week (which may contain the name of a day of the week as shown in my example below).
I've imported the data into Pandas, and tried to use the "in" list function to scan for days of the week, but I'm getting false responses for everything. Here's code that replicates my problem:

```
import pandas as pd

# First example - Testing it in regular code:
x = 'Monday,Tuesday'
dayslist = x.split(",") # redundant, just for testing/printing
Monday = 'Monday' in x.split(",")
print(dayslist, 'Result:',Monday)
# Gives True as a result

# Second example - Trying to do it in a dataframe.
df = pd.DataFrame({'UniqueID':[1,2,3],
                   'DaysOfWeek':['Monday,Tuesday', 'Wednesday,Thursday,Can work Monday if given advance notice', 'Friday']})
df['DaysList'] = df.DaysOfWeek.str.split(",") #redundant, just for testing/printing
df['Monday'] = 'Monday' in df.DaysOfWeek.str.split(",")
print(df)
# False for every record, should be true for first record.
```

I don't understand why the first example works in regular code, but the second cannot find Monday in the data frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `in` in [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) with lambda function:

```
df['Monday'] = df.DaysOfWeek.str.split(",").apply(lambda x: 'Monday' in x)
```

Or create `DataFrame` and test with [`DataFrame.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) and [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html):

```
df['Monday'] = df.DaysOfWeek.str.split(",", expand=True).eq('Monday').any(axis=1)

print(df)
   UniqueID                                         DaysOfWeek  \
0         1                                     Monday,Tuesday   
1         2  Wednesday,Thursday,Can work Monday if given ad...   
2         3                                             Friday   

                                            DaysList  Monday  
0                                  [Monday, Tuesday]    True  
1  [Wednesday, Thursday, Can work Monday if given...   False  
2                                           [Friday]   False
```

If need matches also in substrings use generator with `any`:

```
df['Monday'] = df.DaysOfWeek.str.split(",").apply(lambda x: any('Monday' in y for y in x))
```

Or add [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
df['Monday'] = df.DaysOfWeek.str.split(",", expand=True).apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('Monday')).any(axis=1)
print (df)
   UniqueID                                         DaysOfWeek  \
0         1                                     Monday,Tuesday   
1         2  Wednesday,Thursday,Can work Monday if given ad...   
2         3                                             Friday   

                                            DaysList  Monday  
0                                  [Monday, Tuesday]    True  
1  [Wednesday, Thursday, Can work Monday if given...    True  
2                                           [Friday]   False
```

Comment: Thanks! I had to modify it slightly to get it to work: df['Monday'] = df.DaysOfWeek.str.split(",").apply(lambda x: 'Monday' in str(x)), apparently sometimes my x is a float.

Comment: Follow up question, how can I modify this to bring back the text that isn't a day of the week? I'm having trouble getting my head around how to construct this, I'm relatively new to Python and don't get to use it very often.

Comment: @9Squirrels - I think the best is create new question, also add expectd output from sample data.